# Delphi application fails to call a simple C++ DLL function

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, delphi-6

I would like to write a C++ DLL and call it from Delphi 6 application. I started with simple HelloWorld code from a tutorial and even though it works very well when called from a C++ program, in Delphi app it results in following error message [image: Error in Delphi 6 application]

**MyDll.h**

```
#ifndef _MY_DLL_H_
#define _MY_DLL_H_

#if defined MY_DLL
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
    MYDLL_API int HelloWorld();
}
#endif
```

**MyDll.cpp**

```
#define MY_DLL

#include <windows.h>
#include "MyDll.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

MYDLL_API int HelloWorld()
{
    return 9;
}
```

**This Delphi code fails to call the DLL**

```
function HelloWorld(): LongInt; cdecl; external 'MyDll.dll' name 'HelloWorld';
```

**While the following C++ code works correctly**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*HelloWorldFunc)();

int main()
{
    HelloWorldFunc _HelloWorldFunc;
    HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll");

    if (hInstLibrary)
    {
        _HelloWorldFunc = (HelloWorldFunc)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "HelloWorld");
        if (_HelloWorldFunc)
        {
            std::cout << "HelloWorld result is " << _HelloWorldFunc() << std::endl;
        }
        FreeLibrary(hInstLibrary);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "DLL Failed To Load!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is produced by the loader as it attempts to load the executable and resolve its dependencies. The error means that the loader failed to do this.

The error code is an [`NTSTATUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc704588.aspx) code, namely `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. That is almost always due to a bitness mismatch. A 32-bit host loading a 64-bit DLL, or vice versa.

Given that Delphi 7 is a 32-bit compiler, it would seem likely that your C++ compiler is a 64-bit compiler. You will need to compile the C++ code with a 32-bit compiler in order to consume it from your 32-bit Delphi code.

Comment: After changing the C++ project options to compile with 32-bit configuration it works correctly with the Delphi application. Thank you!